# Long text is breaking my flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two columns.

In my left column I have a `p` tag.

This `p` tag has a lot of text and goes really wide and outside my column.

When I remove my `p` tag the column layout looks fine.

I've tried setting a `max-width` on the `p` tag but this is not very good responsively. I want the `p` tag to be 100% width of the `col` div.

I want the text to go 100% width and wrap nicely.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

p {
  max-width: 100px; /* I dont want to do this. */
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='col'>
    <p>small amount of text</p>
  </div>

  <div class='col'>
    <p>text very long text very longtext very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `flex-shrink` disabled. Activate it.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='col'>
    <p>small amount of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <p>text very long text very longtext very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

With `flex-shrink` disabled, flex items won't shrink. (Another reason flex items often don't shrink is the `min-width: auto` / `min-height: auto` default. *[Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)* )

Comment: Thanks for the note about "flex item can't shrink past content-size" saved me!